# Xdebug profiling and SOAP client call

Tags: php, soap, xdebug

I wonder why my Webgrind does not show SOAP calls in my function list. I've installed xdebug in version 2 and Webgrind in the latest version. I can see lots of functions calls, includes aso. but even if I have one single file that only does a single SOAP call it does not show in Webgrind.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting one indeed. I know I have to do some trickery with the SOAP extension as it's a bit of a bad boy. If you can come up with a reproducable example, please file a bug at http://bugs.xdebug.org — and I'll have a look. I'll be able to get to it faster if it includes scripts that I can run easily.

Answer (score 0):

Against all warnings I had APD and xdebug running in parallel. Had to disable APD and it works like a charme!